# Possible internship topics for a second year undergraduate student interested in astrophysics

Tags: physics, internship

My question is about a specific field.

I am currently studying as a second year undergraduate in BSc program and I am genuinely curious about the field of theoretical astrophysics. I accept, at this level I do not know how research in this field is going to be, but since later I would be taking most of the courses related to the same, I am asking the following question.

What can be few possible research fields(preferably theoretical) to work in summer(as an intern) so as to get exposure to the field of astrophysics?
Given that I have completed courses in the following topics-
Special relativity, Linear algebra, Electrodynamics, Optics, Mechanics, Thermal physics, Probability, Biophysics.

Comment: Take a course in general relativity when you have the chance! Then come and join us on the dark side in cosmology :)

Answer (score 2):

Yay, astrophysics! That's my field, too. ^_^

**I would focus less on what topics you could work on and more *who* you could work *with*.**

For a research position, I'd suggest asking your physics and/or astronomy faculty if they have any research you can assist them with. This is a fantastic place to start, and it's where the vast majority of astrophysics people get their first research experience. In my experience, these positions are usually paid, but I know of situations where undergrads informally volunteer (and work fewer hours) in order to get the experience and extra advising. If your institution doesn't have any options, see if there's a college or university nearby that does.

You can also volunteer with your college or university at astronomy and physics outreach events. You can also see if there's an observatory or astronomical association near where you live, and see if you can't get involved there. You may find some paid part-time positions through the connections you make there.

For an internship, you can look for astrophysics-like businesses near you and see if they have any openings. There aren't many businesses that specialize in astrophysics, but there are many aerospace businesses. If you're open to looking at any of these, you may find luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I am looking for a productive way to spend my summer so as to learn as much as I can about astrophysics, what would you say about doing a reading project in a topic related to astrophysics over working as an intern in some lab?